# Top 10 values in excel

Tags: excel, function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYbcS.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6V7g.png)

According to given data table, I want to find out the top 10 students on the basis of marks (by using excel query) but I think Max function is not working here. kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Large` with `Match` and `Index` to get the list:-[image]
See the image of my example. I have used dummy values.

```
Step1 :- Use this formula (I have used in D column 'Top 10')

  =INDEX($A$2:$B$13,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$B$13,ROW(1:1)),$B$2:$B$13,0),1)

Step2:- Then drag this formula down for 10 rows. You will get the top 10.
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: It served the purpose well. thank you for the elaboration.

Comment: @iramakbar if this has helped you in anyway. You can accept the answer. Please visit this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -1):

Try the rank functions.The original RANK has been deprecated. You can use RANK.EQ instead.

The syntax is

=RANK.EQ(value, entireRangeOfValues).

e.g. =RANK.EQ(J2,$J$2:$J$8015,0)

The last parameter allows you to specify sort order.

Depending on your needs you can also look at RANK.AVG
These differ in how they rank duplicate values.

Comment: Given the rank order not the name.